# SurfaceView overlay

Tags: android, view, overlay, surfaceview

I have a surfaceview which is running couple of threads. One of those threads is drawing on a surfaceview canvas - kind of animation.
Now I would like to "overlay" one image (transparent) - to appear above surfaceview.
This would look something similar to HTC help - overlays help text.
One of the threads will set this overlay when requested (and also clear it when requested).
What would be most simple way to do this?
Should I put surfaceview in a framelayout with another ImageView?
I have to do this programatically.

Answer (score 0):

Check the answers on this one [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3956300/overlay-an-android-layout-on-a-surfaceview?rq=1) .. I hope this would be helpful. Another way is to create your own component, either based on View or based on SurfaceView but it's more advanced.

Answer (score 0):

I added an ImageView component and set/remove "overlay" image from surface thread as needed. It works, but I don't like the "timing" solution - this overlay should popup with a delay and remove it self automatically after some period of time.

What I did is:

Somewhere in surface thread:

```
if (condition) {
    postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        // set overlay image

        postDelayed(new Runnable(){

            // remove overlay image

        }, hideDelay);

    }, showDelay);
}
```

I don't like this nested postDelayed.
I tried using sleep but it just doesn't work as I would have expeceted => overlay imageview will not invalidate until sleep runs out (also tried manually calling invalide).

Any thoughts on this one?